# How do i import an image without PIL in python?

Tags: python

How do i import an image in **python** *without* **PIL**
and also when i print the text will appear above the image?
IN pycharm or VS Code

Comment: you can use opencv also.

Comment: Python doesn't import images at all. PIL is library for *working* with specific binary formats that are used to interpret data as an image. You can load the contents of the file in to memory just fine with vanilla Python: `image = open("foo.jpg", 'rb').read()`. What you *do* with `image` once you have it is a different matter.

Comment: how are you displaying the image?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [openCV](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imread-method/).

```
pip install opencv-python
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("path")
```